# Excel VBA: Convert DateTime string to German DateTime format (constant string length)

Tags: excel, vba, datetime-format

In consequence of a new installation of windows (different language) some log files now have a *different DateTime format*.
To make my Excel/VBA scripts work again I have to convert DateTime strings to the old (German) time format of **constant length**.
To make it clear: I want to **manipulate a string** (not getting another datatype).

```
Problematic Format      =>  Wanted Format
"12/28/2019 9:37:49 PM" => "28.12.2019 21:37:49"
"1/2/2020 10:15:20 AM" =>  "02.01.2020 10:15:20"
"2/1/2020 7:10:15 AM" =>   "01.02.2020 07:10:15"
"2/13/2020 7:10:15 AM" =>  "13.02.2020 07:10:15"
```

One problem I face is that the "Problematic format" has a variable string length. That means I am not able to extract specific positions inside this string using `LEFT / MID / RIGHT`.
Is there any easy possibility to convert this string into the old format **without loops**?

The following Code is not working because of a strange/inconsistent behavior of Excel:

```
ProblematicFormat$ = "2/1/2020 7:10:15 AM"
MyDate = CDate(ProblematicFormat$)
NewDateTime$ = Format(MyDate, "dd.MM.yyyy H:nn:ss")
MsgBox NewDateTime$
```

The result of that code mixes up day and month:

```
"2/1/2020 7:10:15 AM" =>   "02.01.2020 07:10:15" (wrong)
"2/13/2020 7:10:15 AM" =>  "13.02.2020 07:10:15" (correct)
```

Comment: Do you need a solution able to work only for the German localization?

Comment: In my case, yes.

Comment: Being a matter of string manipulation, I will post a piece of code able to adapt your one.

Answer (score 1):

Being a matter of string manipulation, try this code, please:

```
Sub testDateFormatLocale()
Dim ProblematicFormat$, replacement$, toReplace$, MyDate As Date, NewDateTime$, CorrectDateTime$
  'Debug.Print Now, Format(Now, "dd\/mm\/yyyy hh:nn:ss")
  ProblematicFormat$ = "2/13/2020 7:10:15 AM"
  MyDate = CDate(ProblematicFormat$) 'm/dd/yyyy
  NewDateTime$ = Format(MyDate, "dd.MM.yyyy H:nn:ss")
  Debug.Print NewDateTime$
  replacement = Split(NewDateTime, ".", 3)(1) & "." & Split(NewDateTime, ".", 3)(0)
  toReplace = Split(NewDateTime, ".", 3)(0) & "." & Split(NewDateTime, ".", 3)(1)
  CorrectDateTime$ = Replace(NewDateTime$, toReplace, replacement)
  Debug.Print CorrectDateTime$
End Sub
```

You can apply the above solution only for German localization. It can be done using:

```
Debug.Print Application.International(xlCountrySetting)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the region and language setting. In the formats tab, change the format to US (*mm/dd/yyyy*). In case you do not want to change regional settings then you will have to handle the above date using `Split/Dateserial` and then you will get what you want. Something like this...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim oldDateString As String
    Dim newDateString As String
    Dim d As Integer
    Dim m As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim MyDate As Date
    
    oldDateString = "2/1/2020 7:10:15 AM"
    oldDateString = Split(oldDateString)(0)
    d = Val(Split(oldDateString, "/")(1))
    m = Val(Split(oldDateString, "/")(0))
    y = Val(Split(oldDateString, "/")(2))
    
    MyDate = DateSerial(y, m, d)
    Debug.Print MyDate
    
    newDateString = Format(MyDate, "dd.MM.yyyy H:nn:ss")
    Debug.Print newDateString
End Sub
```

Or you can use this? This checks the regional settigns and then decides what to do...

```
Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias _
"GetLocaleInfoA" (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, _
ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long

Private Const LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT = &H400
Private Const LOCALE_SSHORTDATE = &H1F

Private Sub Sample()
    Dim LocaleValue As String
    Dim RetValue As Long
    
    LocaleValue = Space(255)
    RetValue = GetLocaleInfo(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, LOCALE_SSHORTDATE, _
               LocaleValue, Len(LocaleValue))
     
    '~~> Get short date format
    LocaleValue = Ucase(Trim(Left(LocaleValue, RetValue - 1)))

    If Left(LocaleValue, 1) = "M" Then 'M/d/yyyy ???
        '~~> Use your original code
    ElseIf Left(LocaleValue, 1) = "D" Then 
        '~~> Use the code that I gave
    End If
End Sub
```

**Note:** There are different formats that you may come across. The above code will help you handle all those formats, with a little tweak of course.

Comment: Can you adjust your example so that it also adds the time to `newDateString`? Then it would be a good solution for me.

Comment: yes I can. But would you like to give it a try first? Works on the same principle. Using `Split/TimeSerial` ;)

Comment: The complicated thing is the AM/PM. In that case maybe CDate(...) would do a good job.

Comment: I've edited your answer. Now it works with date AND time.

Comment: no no. It will not work like that always. You will have to handle them like I mentioned.

Comment: Do you have an example where it doesn't work in the way I have changed it? In my case it is working without any problem (even AM/PM).

Comment: Excel has an uncanny habit of forcing the American date format **mm/dd/yyyy**. `?format(Cdate("2/1/2020"),"dd-mmm-yyyy")` will give you `01-Feb-2020` on some pcs and `02-Jan-2020` on others

Answer (score 0):

You can use this function which "eats" even quite weird US formatted strings:

```vb
' Converts a US formatted date/time string to a date value.
'
' Examples:
'   7/6/2016 7:00 PM    -> 2016-07-06 19:00:00
'   7/6 7:00 PM         -> 2018-07-06 19:00:00  ' Current year is 2018.
'   7/6/46 7:00 PM      -> 1946-07-06 19:00:00
'   8/9-1982 9:33       -> 1982-08-09 09:33:00
'   2/29 14:21:56       -> 2039-02-01 14:21:56  ' Month/year.
'   2/39 14:21:56       -> 1939-02-01 14:21:56  ' Month/year.
'   7/6/46 7            -> 1946-07-06 00:00:00  ' Cannot read time.
'   7:32                -> 1899-12-30 07:32:00  ' Time value only.
'   7:32 PM             -> 1899-12-30 19:32:00  ' Time value only.
'   7.32 PM             -> 1899-12-30 19:32:00  ' Time value only.
'   14:21:56            -> 1899-12-30 14:21:56  ' Time value only.
'
' 2018-03-31. Gustav Brock. Cactus Data ApS, CPH.
'
Public Function CDateUs( _
    ByVal Expression As String) _
    As Date
    
    Const PartSeparator As String = " "
    Const DateSeparator As String = "/"
    Const DashSeparator As String = "-"
    Const MaxPartCount  As Integer = 2

    Dim Parts           As Variant
    Dim DateParts       As Variant
    
    Dim DatePart        As Date
    Dim TimePart        As Date
    Dim Result          As Date
    
    ' Split expression into maximum two parts.
    Parts = Split(Expression, PartSeparator, MaxPartCount)
    
    
    If IsDate(Parts(0)) Then
        ' A date or time part is found.
        ' Replace dashes with slashes.
        Parts(0) = Replace(Parts(0), DashSeparator, DateSeparator)
        If InStr(1, Parts(0), DateSeparator) > 1 Then
            ' A date part is found.
            DateParts = Split(Parts(0), DateSeparator)
            If UBound(DateParts) = 2 Then
                ' The date includes year.
                DatePart = DateSerial(DateParts(2), DateParts(0), DateParts(1))
            Else
                If IsDate(CStr(Year(Date)) & DateSeparator & Join(DateParts, DateSeparator)) Then
                    ' Use current year.
                    DatePart = DateSerial(Year(Date), DateParts(0), DateParts(1))
                Else
                    ' Expression contains month/year.
                    DatePart = CDate(Join(DateParts, DateSeparator))
                End If
            End If
            If UBound(Parts) = 1 Then
                If IsDate(Parts(1)) Then
                    ' A time part is found.
                    TimePart = CDate(Parts(1))
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ' A time part it must be.
            ' Concatenate an AM/PM part if present.
            TimePart = CDate(Join(Parts, PartSeparator))
        End If
    End If
    
    Result = DatePart + TimePart
        
    CDateUs = Result

End Function
```

Then apply your format, for example:

```vb
? Format(CDateUS("1/2/2020 10:15:20 AM"), "dd.mm.yyyy hh:nn:ss")
02.01.2020 10:15:20
```